# Schengen Visa 90/180

Tags: schengen-visas, 90-180-visa-rules

My situation is the following:

1. I had a Visa issued from 20.9 till 20.12 for 90 days.
2. I stayed in Croatia for 80 days, I went back to my country @ 20.12 and my visa has ended.

does the 90/180 still apply even if i issued a new visa as my last one has ended?

I called the embassy and they told me it is per visa so if my visa has ended, I am eligible to apply for a new visa and stay for the period specified in the new Visa regardless of the history of the old visa.

However my friends are telling me that it still applies regardless ir your visa has ended or not so the rule isn't per visa and I am now pretty confused as they said they may accept the visa however, the officer can refuse my entry.

Does anyone has a similar experience?!

Comment: If you had already stayed in the Schengen area, a new visa would not reset your 'clock'. Croatia is however not part of the Schengen area and any stay there does not count on the 90/180 days rule.

Comment: I believe rules are different for single-entry visas or visas with a shorter duration, but it's quite probable they will enforce the 90/180 rule by not issuing a visa valid before 10/3, or a visa valid before that but only for 10 days, for instance.

Comment: @jcaron, the 90/180 rule applies to any combination of short-stay (C) Schengen visa, except for a few specific cases with pre-existing treaties which got grandfathered in.

Comment: Did you go do Croatia on a visa issued by some other country?  I'm confused what this has to do with Schengen, since Croatia is not a Schengen member. Where are you looking to go next -- Croatia again?

Comment: @o.m. as far as I know, those bilateral agreement exceptions all apply to visa-free travel, so they would not apply here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Even though Croatia is not fully integrated into the Schengen area, it [allows people who hold Schengen visas to visit on the basis of the Schengen visa](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/).

Comment: @phoog: True. But it still sounds strange to get a visa from a Schengen country and then apparently only use it to go to Croatia. (If the OP has a Schengen visa it doesn't sound like he would have had time to go to the issuing country at all). And if he's looking to go to Schengen _now_, what matters is how long he was _there_ before, not how long he was in Croatia.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh I see. The question doesn't say that it's a Schengen visa.  It could have been a Croatian visa, with the contemplated subsequent trip also to Croatia.  The answer would then be the same as for a Schengen visa and a Schengen country.

Comment: @phoog, I wonder if there is a list of these exceptions. Usually I think of Poland/US ...

Comment: @phoog: The _title_ of the question says "Schengen Visa", so I remain confused, and I think the OP needs to clarify.

Comment: @HenningMakholm oh yes.  It's easy to overlook the title.

Answer (score 0):

The 90/180 rule applies across visas.  This means that your ability to use a second visa might be restricted in a way that isn't obvious from reading the visa itself.

For example, suppose you spent 80 days in the Schengen area with a 90-day visa.  Two months later, you get a new 90-day visa.  If your second entry is within 90 days of your previous departure,  you would only be able to stay for 10 days.  However, you would have 80 days remaining that you would be able to use during the latter part of the visa's validity, as long as your third entry is more than 180 days after your first.

If your visa really was a Schengen visa, though, time spent in Croatia counts separately from time spent in the Schengen area, so depending on your plans, you may be fine.